# Access MAC address from sk_buff

Tags: linux

I'm writing a kernel module to get the MAC address from a packet stored in sk_buff. I've used the following code to print the MAC address of source and destination:

```
struct ethhdr *mh = eth_hdr(skb);  
printk(KERN_EMERG "Source MAC=%x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x\n",mh->h_source[0],mh->h_source[1],mh->h_source[2],mh->h_source[3],mh->h_source[4],mh->h_source[5]);
```

The destination address can be accessed using `h_dest` inplace of `h_source`.
My problem is that the source MAC address is always `a8:c0:0:0:a8:c0` and the destination MAC address is always some junk value instead of my own MAC address.
Can anyone help me out on this? I want to get the correct MAC addresses.

Comment: You can use %pM to print mac addresses with printk.

Answer (score 5):

Where exactly in the kernel are you doing this?

a8:c0 looks quite suspicious. It translates to 168.192 in decimal, which makes me suspect that you're in fact looking at the IPv4 header rather than the Ethernet header.

Answer (score 3):

Using `eth_hdr` only makes sense if the skb actually *has* a MAC header. If it does not, the skb's MAC header pointer will just point to other data in the packet.

Answer (score 1):

Using `mac_len` can help you solve this issue. Usually you will get 14 (6 for destination mac + 6 for source mac + 2 for protocol) bytes or 0 (packet came from loopback). Note that if this returns 0, `eth_hdr` will point directly to the data (in case of ip protocol to an ip header) and not to the ethernet frame header, as jørgensen said.

To get a mac for non-zero mac_len, you can directly use the pointer returned by `eth_hdr`:

```
struct ethhdr* pHdr = eth_hdr(skb);  
printk(KERN_EMERG "Source MAC=%x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x\n", pHdr[6], pHdr[7], pHdr[8], pHdr[9], pHdr[10], pHdr[11]);
```

If you are interested in computing mac addresses for a loopback packet, see `protocol` field. For example if it equals 08 00 (8), you can get the mac from the destination ip address. If the address is ff:ff:ff:ff, you know the mac was ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff (broadcast). If not, use the mac address of the device, or anything you would prefer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be processing the packet at Layer 2 in order to access the ethernet header. If your linux kernel module is getting the packet at Layer 3 (Netfilter hook) so the MAC address doesn't exist in the packet.